# Cannot retrieve uint Array from Struct in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct, truffle-test

I have the following struct in my contract

```
struct Transaction {
    TransactionType transactionType;
    uint256 id;
    uint256 productId;
    uint256 timestamp;
    address from;
    address to;
    uint256[] source;
    uint256 test;
}
```

which I then initialize like this

```
uint256[] memory source = new uint256[](1);
source[0] = 55;
Transaction memory transaction = Transaction(*other params*, source, 999);
```

In a test where I let above code run and examine the transaction in the debugger it looks like the following:

[image]

The object is supposed to contain 8 elements, but only 7 are shown.
Following the address fields at indices 4/5 is the uint field **test**.

What happened to the array field **source**?

Comment: The `source` array will not be accessible from the native getter when queries from web3. You may have to implement your own getter to retrieve the struct's array elements. See an earlier answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63493/how-do-i-read-an-array-inside-of-a-struct.

Comment: I was able to work out the problem based on your answer. Writing a getter for the transaction in my contract yielded the expected result. Thank you for saving me further headache and apologies for not searching properly before posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types (arrays, mappings, struct) that are part of the structure are not being returned when you try to return structure data. You can notice that only value types are returned.

You should create a function that would act as a getter that will access the data you need and return it back.

For your example:

```
function getSources(uint transactionId) external returns (uint[] memory sources) {
      sources = transactions[transactionId].sources; // In case you have array of transactions
}
```