# How to get struct arrays within structs in ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, arrays, struct

My code:

```
struct C {
    address addr;
    uint amount;
}

struct Item {
    uint a;
    uint b;
    C[] itemCs;
    int d;
    uint e;
    int f;
    uint g;
}

mapping(uint => Item) public idToItem;
```

I want to read an `Item` from my contract. I'm calling:

`console.log("item:", await contract.idToItem(0));`

I get:

```
item: [
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  BigNumber { value: "5" },
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  a: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  b: BigNumber { value: "5" },
  d: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  e: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  f: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  g: BigNumber { value: "0" }
]
```

Where are `itemCs`? How do I get them?

Comment: See here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118509/cannot-retrieve-uint-array-from-struct-in-solidity Hope it helps!