# Why is my two dimension array undefined in ethersjs?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I have the following struct inside my contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

library MyLibrary {

struct SaleTrack {
    uint256 index;
    uint256 postDate;
    uint32[][] tixToEv;
  }
```

And Im logging these values within my test like this:

```js
it("...", async function () {
    console.log(saleTrack.tixToEv); Logs *undefined*
  });
```

However, my smart contract has the following snippet to check the result of the saleTrack struct:

```js
console.logUint(myNestedMapping[organizer][contract].tixToEv[indexSerieToUpdate][1]); // Logs 360 inside hardhat node i.e the number I expected
```

This is the mapping that uses the SaleTrack struct Im referring to:

```js
mapping(address => mapping(address => MarketPlaceLibrary.SaleTrack))
    public myNestedMapping;
```

Any ideas on why ethersjs is not able to get those values from the struct contained within the mapping?

Comment: What Solidity version are you using?

Comment: For the compiler Im using 0.8.12

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that reference types (arrays, mappings, struct) that are part of the structure are not being returned when you try to return structure data. You can notice that only value types are returned.

I need to create a function that would act as a getter that will access the data you need and return it back. More info here:
[Cannot retrieve uint Array from Struct in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118509/cannot-retrieve-uint-array-from-struct-in-solidity)